# Generate range of sequential number without repetition

Tags: javascript, html

Can anyone please help me with the code. im trying to generate numbers from range 12012300 to 12012400 in sequence and without repetition. Will be great if message is displayed saying generated number is reserved, below the textbox.

Thanks heaps in advance

```
<form>
 <input name="code" id="code" type="text" placeholder="#########" value="" readonly /> 

        <script type="text/javascript"> 
          function makeid() {
            return Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 12012300;
          }
        </script>
        <input type="button" value="Generate Code" onclick="document.getElementById('code').value = makeid()"></input>
       <input type="reset" value="Reset" />
</form>
```

Comment: We are not an entity that would do the work for your... You need to specify the problem better... show us where you are stuck...
But evaluation your problem, it isn't only a matter of adding +1 from 12012300 to 12012400?

Comment: is the result one random number as it is implied in code...or is it a range of sequential numbers as it is explained in question?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I am trying to generate range of sequential numbers. One per click without repetition inside the textbox. Code was pasted was just to show I have 1 textbox and generate button. it is section of my page.Please ignore the Random part.

Comment: Hi Guys, im sorted now. I have sorted my code with jquery and python in django. Numbers in the table are set to checked once generated.I have loaded the numbers manually from admin page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the basic example of closure, self-invoking function

If you need sequential numbers you do not need to use `Math.random`

```js
let makeid = (() => {
 let id = 12012300;
 return () => {
  if(id > 12012400 ) throw( 'max id reached')
  return id++;
 };
})();

console.log(makeid())
console.log(makeid())
console.log(makeid())
```